# PHP Timer stop re-starting when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php

I have a timer for my Quiz web application but the timer does reset every time the user goes to the next question or when he refresh the page.

I tried to save the remaining time to a variable but, i don't know. I am beginner and some would be helpful.

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
<script>
var seconds = 15;
    function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        header("location:account.php?q=result&eid=5cb44b236f3b1");
    } else {    
        seconds--;
    }
    }
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

I would like to have this timer the same for every page or every time the user refresh the page.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: a php script just runs _once_ and doesn't remember what happened the last time is was called. So you'd need to somehow remember the remaining seconds - easiest in a $_SESSION variable. Look into [sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) on how to implement that. _OR_ save them in the user's browser (as cookie, in localStorage) - but be aware that the user can change those stored values. _OR_ don't reload the script when the user goes to the next question -> look into ajax

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to use session variable.  What you do is store the time at which the quiz was started and run your count down based on that.  Note you will only need to set the startTime variable on the first page.

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

if($_SESSION["startTime"] == null)
{
  $_SESSION["startTime"] = time();
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Timer script
// Get start time of quiz, current time and calculate time remaining
var startTime = "<?php echo $_SESSION["startTime"] ?>"; 

//...Rest of timer script.

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I understand the logic behind this but I still don't know how exactly I should implement this in my page. :(

Comment: I have edited my code.  Now we check if the session variable is null we set to the current time.  This variable will now persist throughout your users session and can be accessed after refreshing pages or moving between pages.

Comment: Didn't work, maybe I did something wrong but it is not working, still reset on refresh..

Answer (score 0):

To save data and share with another pages, You need to use Storage.
In client side we have `Cookie Storage`, `Local Storage` and `Session Storage (Client Side)`. And in server side we can use `cookie` and `Session (server side)`.

So first of all you need to save the current remaining second at the end, So each time when you reduce the second, You need to update storage also.

When you refresh the site, First of all you need to get the remaining second from storage. If there is no data (At first time may be), You need to load the default time, Otherwise load the remaining time.

Look this, Here I used local storage.

```
<div id='countdown'></div>

<script>

    var seconds = localStorage.getItem('remainTime'); //gettting saved time from localstorage

    if(seconds == null || seconds == undefined){
      seconds = 15; //default time
    }

    function secondPassed() {
      var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
      var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
      if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
          remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
      }
      document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
      if (seconds == 0) {
          clearInterval(countdownTimer);
          header("location:account.php?q=result&eid=5cb44b236f3b1");
      } else {    
          seconds--;
          localStorage.setItem('remainTime',seconds); //saving time to localstorage
      }
    }


    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOGRpp

But its better to save it on your `SESSION` and update it using `Ajax request`. (For more secure purpose)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Yes You are right, I updated my answer, Thank you @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0):

I also needed such a timer for my security concept when updating user data and have now found it.

Here is my code for it: (I've used codeigniter for my solution)

```
session()->set('can_edit_profile_until', time() + 300); // 5 minutes
```

The Code where I check this:

```
$session = session();
        
        if( ! $session->has('can_edit_profile_until')) {

            return redirect()->to("/profile/authenticate");
        }
```

The JavaScript I've found here in SO:

```
<?php
$remaining_time = session()->get('can_edit_profile_until') - time();
?>
<script>
    var seconds = <?= $remaining_time ?>;
    function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;
        }
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" +    remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Expired";
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

and the display-code:

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```

If there are any questions I will help them to answer.